# LiveData.value returns Null But Livedata Direct Observe it getting result

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

[View Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djBjx.png)

When I want to set live-data to mutable live data I call live data.getvalue() but it returns null

private const val TAG = "MainViewModel"

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: VaultRepository) : ViewModel() {
private var dashMutableData = MutableLiveData<List>()
var dashLiveData: LiveData<List> = dashMutableData

```
init {
    Log.d(TAG, " Init Executed ")
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        var liveData: LiveData<List<CategoriesModel>> = repository.getDashBoardData()
        Log.d(TAG, "${liveData.value}")
        dashMutableData.postValue(liveData.value)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show code of Activity/Fragment where you observe your LiveData and code of `MainViewModel`?

Comment: viewModel.dashLiveData.observe(this, Observer{
            it?.let {
                Log.d(TAG, "LiveData: ${it.toString()}")
            }
        })

Comment: Please do not use images to show your code. Use a code snippet or use markdown to display your code. It makes it easier for others to debug your code and makes your questions easier to answer.

Comment: My any desk id i will give you bro can u help me

Answer (score 0):

Why return `LiveData` from your repository if you are not going to observe it? You could just return `List<CategoriesModel>` from your repository.

`LiveData` does not have a value unless it has an observer. If you add an observer, it will get a value once the observer has triggered once.

You shouldn't do this, but just to prove the point, if you add an observer before accessing the value it should work:

```
init {
    Log.d(TAG, " Init Executed ")
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        var liveData: LiveData<List<CategoriesModel>> = repository.getDashBoardData()
        livedata.observeForever(object: Observer<T> {
            override fun onChanged(value: T) {
                removeObserver(this)
            }
        })
        delay(100) //not sure this is needed, just making sure the observer triggered once.
        dashMutableData.postValue(liveData.value)
        Log.d(TAG, "${liveData.value}")
    }
}
```

Comment: In Viewmodel we cant get content how can we pass content in observeForever